# Android gradle build: duplicate files during packaging of APK LICENSE.txt

Tags: android, gradle, android-build

I am trying to build an Android test using the following gradle build file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
    }

apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    instrumentTestCompile "junit:junit:4.+"        
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    instrumentTest {
      java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
      res.srcDirs = ['tests/res']
      assets.srcDirs = ['tests/assets']
      resources.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
        }        
    }
}
```

When run I get the following error:

> Error: duplicate files during packaging of APK ...    Path in archive: LICENSE.txt
>       Origin 1: ....gradle/caches/artifacts-24/filestore/junit/junit/4.11/jar/4e031bb61df09069aeb2bffb4019e7a5034a4ee0/junit-4.11.jar
>       Origin 2: ....gradle/caches/artifacts-24/filestore/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/jar/42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
>   :packageTest FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':packageTest'.
>     Duplicate files at the same path inside the APK: LICENSE.txt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Junit v4.5 has packaged all necessary dependencies into the JUnit jar. Hence no need for hamcrest.jar, and no resulting double LICENSE.txt file.

just change dependencies to:

> instrumentTestCompile "junit:junit:4.5+"

The basic issue still remains - android not accepting two files names the same in its build tree. 
This is a good workaround, though.

Comment: +1, In idle situations, using "junit:junit:4.+" would resolve to anything greater than 4.0 which includes 4.5+. But studio/gradle has this problem where it doesn't refresh the dependencies or looks for newer dependencies at times. The workaround would be ignore cache and reload the dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

I noticed this commit comment in AOSP, the solution will be to exclude some files using DSL. Probably when 0.7.1 is released.

```
commit e7669b24c1f23ba457fdee614ef7161b33feee69
Author: Xavier Ducrohet <--->
Date:   Thu Dec 19 10:21:04 2013 -0800

    Add DSL to exclude some files from packaging.

    This only applies to files coming from jar dependencies.
    The DSL is:

    android {
      packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
      }
    }
```

Comment: I added excludes for license.txt. It doesn't help with studio. When I build/run tests from terminal it works perfect, but when I am trying to run it from inside android studio, it complains about duplicate files